# javascript- why can't a member of an object be called without 'this' from a function within the same scope?

Tags: javascript, web

When creating objects with member values of objects, why is the `'this'` keyword needed to call other members within the same scope? In the following code, for example, this.name had to be called from `function()`. Why can `function()` here not be able to access name without using `'this'`? My understanding is that a function is executed when it is called and the value (Brian) at the time of execution would theoretically be already declared and available...

Why does this work:

```
var person2 = {
      name: 'Brian',
      greeting: function() {
        alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
      }
    }
```

but not this:

```
var person2 = {
          name: 'Brian',
          greeting: function() {
            alert('Hi! I\'m ' + name + '.');
          }
        }
```

Comment: It *is* declared, *but* its not a variable in scope but a property of an object. This is javascript not java ( there such weird stuff works ;))

Comment: why is it not available though? function() is inner while the name is in the outer scope, so function should be able to access it?

Comment: IT IS NOT IN SCOPE. the object is in scope ( so you could do `person2.name` ( not recommended though)

Comment: this is what I don't get, why is it not in scope? a variable declared locally would be, but this is not..

Comment: Because an object property is *not* a variable. The object is the variable.

Comment: just had an aha moment thx.